# Wp-load outside wordpress makes page blank

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am using this code `require('wp-load.php');` to include `wp-load.php` in my php script. But Somehow its giving me blank page and after enabling error reporting there is no error displayed.

Comment: are you checked with @require('wp-load.php') ; ?

Comment: Just tried @ but its still blank after file inclusion. Any other solution?

Comment: check Is there any die() or any other command exists which stops the script?

Comment: nopes, there is no die() used.
here is my code:
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
echo "file test<br>";
@require('wp-load.php');
echo "after file load";

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure error reporting is 'on' in the php.ini file. I think 
error_reporting is 'off'  in your php.ini file.  Please turn it 'on' .so that you can track the error.

Comment: 2 entries in php.ini dictate the output of errors:

display_errors ,
error_reporting

Comment: error_reporting is already enabled and I have checked error logs aswell and there are no as such errors found. Any other solution?

Comment: try    require_once('../../../wp-load.php');

Comment: Will this work because wp-load and my files both are at same location.

Comment: where are are you using this code plugin page or theme page ?

Comment: Inside public_html that is in the root.

Comment: if you comment the line , is there showing the blank page ?

Comment: If I comment require part then it works, only after including wp-load.php makes my page blank.

Answer (score 0):

In my case issue was with short codes. Short codes were not enabled and finally problem is solved. Thank you everyone for posting out the possible solutions.